# How can I include and use a proc from another file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I am using rails_admin and the options of how to configure models with rails_admin seems to be having one rails_admin.rb config file (but this file would be huge and I'd have to restart the server after each change):

```
RailsAdmin.config do |config|
   config.model ModelName do
       ..
```

or including a config block within each model:

```
 class ModelName
     rails_admin do
         ..
```

But I'd rather not have the config block within the model because these blocks are getting really long.

So I initially tried creating mixins from each config block for a model:

```
  module ModelNameAdmin
      rails_admin do
          ...
```

That didn't work because it didn't recognize rails_admin.

Doing this didn't work either:

```
 module ModelNameAdmin
     RailsAdmin.config do |config|
         config.model ModelName do
```

But this didn't work because apparently the RailsAdmin config can't be called more than once.

So now would I'd like to do is just have a lib file with a Proc defined, that I could include and use in each model.  So like:

```
  model ModelName
       require('./lib/model_name_admin')

       rails_admin do
            @model_name_admin
       end
```

And in the ./lib/model_name_admin file have:

```
  @model_name_admin = Proc.new
       rails_admin do
           ..
```

But this doesn't work.  I don't think I'm using the proc correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this pattern with your module:

```
module ModelNameAdmin
  def self.included(base)
    base.class_eval do
      rails_admin do
        #...
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The block within `class_eval` will be executed whenever the module is included in a class.